# Can't see any change on the website even if I change the CSS file

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I used to see the changes I was making yesterday. And now I change the simply the color and the other things no change. This is really annoying and happened to me multiple times. I don't see any overriding file either. I checked the other similar problems and questions but couldn't solve it. So, if you can give me the logic behind the problem and the solution so that I don't encounter it again that would be very kind.

Here's the shortened CSS code:

```
.page-header {
    background-color: #421557;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 40px;
}
```

And here's the HTML code:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Blog</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/blog.css' %}">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="page-header">
            <h1><a href="/">Blog</a></h1>
        </div>

        {% for post in posts %}
            <div class="post">
                <p>published: {{ post.published_date }}</p>
                <h1><a href="">{{ post.title }}</a></h1>
                <p>{{ post.text|linebreaksbr }}</p>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Whenever I mess up with Bootstrap, I get angry. I think I still didn't get the idea.

Comment: caching problem?

Comment: Yes, it turns out it is. It is the first time I am hearing about this problem and checked it on Google. After applying some solutions, everything worked just fine. Thank you.